# Retrieving user information from facebook React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a scenario where I am allowing a user to log in using Facebook Login button. Later on for some other page I have to fetch the users profile picture. Should I use AsyncSotrage to store the access token and make a call to the graph api for fetching the required information? Currently this is all the code I have in my login page.

```
       <LoginButton 
             publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
             onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
             if (error) {
            alert("login has error: " + result.error);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             alert("login is cancelled.");
            } else {
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
               (data) => {       
               try {

                    AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
                    console.log(data);
                    } catch (error)
                     {
                                        // Error saving data
                      }                   
                    }
            )
          }
        }
      }
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few easy methods to get info from default Asynk Storage. It's recommended to store private user data (like an access tokens or passwords) in Keychain Storage.
You can use for it react-native-keychain.

Also you can implement your own private keychain-based async storage with this package. Or just data transform. It's useful if you have redux-persist.
Here is an example how to implement it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Storage/AsyncStorage.js

Hope it will help.